# Null pointer exception while restoring value

Tags: android

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    for(int i=0;
    i<teeth.length;
    i++)
    {
        teeth[i]=(Integer) savedInstanceState.get("Id"+"["+i+"]");
        if(teeth[i]!=0)
        {
            teeth[i]=i+1;
            backselection.add(teeth[i]);
            Ateeth[i].setBackgroundResource(imgid[i]);
            currentselection.setText("CurrentSelection:"+backselection);
        }
    }
}
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    for(int i=0;
    i<teeth.length;
    i++)
    {
        outState.putInt("Id"+"["+i+"]", teeth[i]);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: I think that there's something missing here, as well as a question.

Comment: Interesting code, seems like from first Windows secret code ))))

Comment: am getting null pointer exception in restore method

Comment: You should provide code in the code section. Also consider that it's also good practice to provide the logcat log in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `getInt()`

```
savedInstanceState.getInt("Id"+"["+i+"]", 0);  //0 is default value
```